# using variable for name file in save - matlb

Tags: matlab, file, nsworkspace

I am trying to save part of my workspace in matlab.
lets say .

```
    a=1 
    b=3
    name1='file_a.mat'
    save(name1,a)
```

and got

```
Error using save
Argument must contain a character vector.
```

I also tried .

```
save name1 a
```

this generated a file named name1 (instead of file_a.mat) . 
I am using matlab 2017 on mac .

thank you

Comment: [The documentation for `save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) explains the inputs and their necessary data type(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the *variable* you want to save must be passed to `save` as a string:

```
a=1 
b=3
name1='file_a.mat'
%          v-v here
save(name1,'a')
```